# Problem in installing Julia in atom editor, Error: "unknown package Atom"?

Tags: installation, julia, atom-editor

My Julia version is 0.6.4. I am facing problem of installing Julia. I had it installing for so long, but all of a sudden julia stopped starting in REPL. Therefore, I deleted the julia and Atom, an trying to reinstall it eversince. Please give me suggestions. Below is the output when I start Julia in REPL:

```
Hold on tight while we're installing some packages for you.
This should only take a few seconds...

ERROR:LoadError: unknown package Atom
macro expansion at .\pkg\entry.jl:53 [inlined]
(::Base.Pkg.Entry.##1#3{String,Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet})() at .\task.jl:335
Stacktrace:

 [1] 
 sync_end() 
 at .\task.jl:287
 [2] macro expansion at .\task.jl:303 [inlined]
 [3] add(::String, ::Base.Pkg.Types.VersionSet) at .\pkg\entry.jl:51
 [4] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##4#7{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}})() at .\pkg\dir.jl:36
 [5] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##4#7{Array{Any,1},Base.Pkg.Entry.#add,Tuple{String}}, ::String) at .\file.jl:59
 [6] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N} where N) at .\pkg\dir.jl:36
 [7] add(::String) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:117
 [8] include_from_node1(::String) at .\loading.jl:576
 [9] include(::String) at .\sysimg.jl:14
 [10] process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:305
 [11] _start() at .\client.jl:371
 while loading C:\Users\Nitin\.atom\packages\julia-client\script\boot_sync.jl, in expression starting on line 22
 Julia has stopped: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Atom directly on your computer? The error lines seems to suggest you tried installing Atom through the Julia package manager `Pkg`, which would be odd as Atom is a general text editor and not a package ment for usage in `Julia`.

Also, on related note, any particular reason for using Julia 0.6 instead of the now standard 1.0 branches?

Comment: I have Atom IDE installed on my system. This output is obtained when I start Julia in REPL. I am using V.6 because some of my code is written on V.6, and I am not sure about Julia's forward compatibility. Also, I will have to re-install new Julia version on my second computer. No other technical reason.